Tkinter's iconphoto function gives "X error of failed request: BadLength"
I'm on Linux Ubuntu 22.10,  Python 3.10.7, and Tkinter 8.6.
I was trying to make a basic window in Tkinter, but when I tried to run it it gave me this error:
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  0 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  192
  Current serial number in output stream:  192

Fyi, here is the code:
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk() # Make a window
window.geometry("500x500") # Make the window bigger
window.title("Window") # Set the title for the window

image = tk.PhotoImage(file = "image.png") # Make the icon for the window
window.iconphoto(True, image) # Set the icon for the window

window.mainloop() # Display the window

Okay, I looked it up and there wasn't that much information about it. Seems like it doesn't pop up often. Now the only thing I could find about it is something about the "Noto Color Emoji" font, which probably isn't the case since I have no emojis in my file (correct me if I'm wrong). So I did a little bit of troubleshooting.
I removed each of the lines from the file one by one to see which one was causing it, and looks like the line window.iconphoto(True, image) is to blame. Now I'm pretty sure the code is fine (I may or may not have ripped it straight out of a tutorial), so I don't see how it could cause an error. I also tried the fixes for the "Noto Color Emoji" problem, which were installing unifont and uninstalling "Noto Color Emoji", which both didn't work. I also noticed that there's a serial number for the error, and I couldn't find anyone who had the same one as me.
I'm stumped. Can someone help me out here?

Please include info about your environment: OS version, Python version, Tkinter version.

Did you get the same error if different PNG image is used?

Can you reduce the image size?

@auraham just edited the post to include that.

@acw1668
@toyotaSupra
I just tried that, still throws an error, but the "major opcode" becomes: Major opcode of failed request:  76 (X_ImageText8)
The image was compressed from 200KB to 20KB.

One thing is, did you rename the filename before downloading?

Yeah, I did try renaming it. Still didn't work.

@toyotaSupra oops, forgot to ping you.

No, you cannot renaming filename. Try another one with extension such as png, jpg, bmp, etc,. Btw, you can rename it if it is works.  No like this Not from Pinterest, etc,.

@toyotaSupra
Oh wait, I thought you meant renaming the first part of the file, as in "image.png" -> "icon.png". I didn't do something like "image.png" -> "image.image". Sorry for the confusion :P

It is something like this that you download from website th-2455806701 --> image1.png. This doesn't work, while you changing filename.

One thing is to update Python 3.12.

@toyotaSupra when I changed filename I also made sure to change the code, dw. Also, for some reason I can't seem to update python, installing deadsnakes gives a load of 404s.

That all. I can't go further than.

aw man, that sucks. Thanks for the help tho :P
